# Why does MySQL count from 1 and not 0?

Tags: php, python, mysql, ruby

The first element of arrays (in most programming languages) has an id (index) of 0. The first element (row) of MySQL tables has an (auto incremented) id of 1. The latter seems to be the exception.

Comment: Row 0 doesn't quite have a ring to it. First row, however, does. There is also the `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` setting. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero

Comment: Perhaps most programming languages, but not all (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array%5Fsystem%5Fcross-reference%5Flist)

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT values don't impart an array-like data structure onto a table, the rows themselves remain unrelated and unordered. All they do is ensure uniqueness for primary keys. Don't think of them like an indexed data structure!

Comment: They could do the same starting from 0. It might event be friendlier to memory.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev To whose memory? Yours or the server's? Those extra 32 or 64 bits of data won't mean much to the server.

Comment: SQL is generally one-based. Besides, zero is falsey in a lot of languages so if auto-increments started at zero then everyone would be complaining that they couldn't `if(o.id)`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Anyone's. That's not the point. The point is that your comment doesn't answer the question. It also doesn't explain why you would vote to close it.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: The question was poorly written. There's not even a real question up there. Rewrite it and then we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev The conventions for "not constructive" are well established. That's why I and others voted as we did.  And I didn't answer your question, I know - that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: But to build on @muistooshort 's comment - not only auto increment integers are one based.  String indices in substring functions are also 1-based in SQL - still don't think of this as being related to auto-increment values. Their purpose is uniqueness. They could just as well be incremented like `a,b,c,d...aa,ab,ac...zza,zzb...`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I found an answer that makes sense. It's in the comment of Christoph Grimmer-Dietrich. I find it quite constructive.

Comment: Indexing from zero is mostly a historical artifact, a pointer offsetting implementation detail that leaked into reality. If you want to know why MySQL starts at one you'd have to ask the MySQL developers and probably track down all the SQL committee members.

Comment: Getting *really* nerdy, 0 is not a number, it is an absence of a number. Just like black is not a color, it is the absence of light.

@ChrisCooney's answer is spot on. Because 0 is not strictly a value it would be left blank in numerical fields, thus needing to start from 1.

I know you maybe thinking computers use 1 and 0, well yes and like a switch 1 is on 0 is off - off being in this case an absence. There is no Roman Numeral for 0 - yet they still use minus numbers.

I can not find a reliable web source, but this book has it all: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BFJHzSIj2u0C&redir_esc=y

Comment: @VincentSavard, It's a simple question. In the title I ask why A is not B and in the body I explain why I expect it to be B.

Comment: "Should array indices start at 0 or 1? My compromise of 0.5 was rejected without, I thought, proper consideration." - Stan Kelly-Bootle

Answer (score 4):

The better question to ask is "why are arrays zero-indexed?"  The reason has to do with pointer arithmetic.  The index of an array is an offset relative to the pointer address.  In C++, given array `char x[5]`, the expressions `x[1]` and `*(x + 1)` are equivalent, given that `sizeof(char) == 1`.

So auto increment fields starting at 1 make sense.  There is no real correlation between arrays and these fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the start of the auto increment column to any number, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

The default is 1.

See also:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Good to know, but why is that?

Comment: Auto increment is a PK, there is no relation to zero-based numbering for Arrays. It there to make sure a record is unique. You can also define a increment value (n), and make the PK increase by n. So if you start with 1000, and the increment is 10, you get 1010,1020,1030... This might be interesting (related to array's): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I suppose is that a row in a database isnt an array and the autoincrement value isnt an index in the sense that an array index is.  The primary key id can be any value and to a great extent it is simply essential it is unique and is not guaranteed to be anything else (for example you can delete a row and it won't renumber).

This is a little like comparing apples and oranges!

Array start at 0 because that's the first number.  Autoinc fields start at whatever number you want them too, and in that case we would all rather it was 1.